# Programmatically add and delete Combobox, Textbox and Checkbox to Userform - VBA

Tags: vba, controls, userform

[image]I am creating a userform which has 1 combobox (1), 2 textboxes (2 and 3), and 11 checkboxes (A-K) as in picture. The first instance of all controls will be present, but when a user clicks on Add Class, a new set of all controls has to be created and when Remove Class should delete a particular row.

I have managed to get the requirement for one instance, but I could not figure out how do I do it for N times, with the size of the userform to be expanding also.

```
Private Sub cmdAddClass()

 Dim cCheckBox As Control, r As Long, r1 As Range

 Set r1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A12") 

 Set cComboBox = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.ComboBox.1")
 With cComboBox
  .Height=25.5
  .Width=102
  .Top=50
  .Left =6
 End With

 Set cTextBox = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1")
 With cTextBox
  .Height=25.5
  .Width=54
  .Top=50
  .Left =114
 End With

 For r = 1 To WorksheetFunction.CountA(r1)
  If r1(r) <> vbNullString Then 
   Set cCheckBox = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.CheckBox.1", "Checkbox" & r, True)
    With cCheckBox
     .Width = 21
     .Height = 11
     .Top = 50
     If r = 1 Then
       .Left = 270
     ElseIf r = 2 Then
       .Left = 348
     ElseIf r = 3 Then
       .Left = 420
     ElseIf r = 4 Then
       .Left = 492
     ElseIf r = 5 Then
       .Left = 564
     ElseIf r = 6 Then
       .Left = 636
     ElseIf r = 7 Then
       .Left = 701.95
     ElseIf r = 8 Then
       .Left = 780
     ElseIf r = 9 Then
       .Left = 876
     ElseIf r = 10 Then
       .Left = 966
     Else
       .Left = 1050
     End If
    End With
  End If
 Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: Here's several hints to get you started.  First, calculate the value for .Top every time the button is pressed.  Second, you should not expand the size of the form as controls are added.  Rather, you want to implement scrolling.  Third, you will need to reposition the buttons as controls are added and removed.

Comment: How many `N` times do you expect to add new rows?

Comment: @AlexP Maybe around 10-15

Comment: @BrianMStafford Could you please guide me on how do I calculate .Top?

Comment: @Cody Instead of a hard-coded Top of 50, have a module-level or static variable that keeps track of the Top.  Every time you press the button add a number to Top to keep the controls spaced correctly.  What number should you add?  I don't know, just keep adjusting it until you like how the form looks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example you can adapt.

```
Private Sub btnAddClass_Click()
    Dim ctrl As Control, newCtrl As Control, offsetTop As Integer

    offsetTop = 30

    For Each ctrl In Me.Controls

        If TypeName(ctrl) <> "CommandButton" Then
            If ctrl.Top = btnAddClass.Top - offsetTop Then
                If TypeName(ctrl) = "ComboBox" Then
                    Set newCtrl = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.ComboBox.1")
                ElseIf TypeName(ctrl) = "TextBox" Then
                    Set newCtrl = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1")
                ElseIf TypeName(ctrl) = "CheckBox" Then
                    Set newCtrl = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.Checkbox.1")
                End If

                With newCtrl
                    .Height = ctrl.Height
                    .Width = ctrl.Width
                    .Top = ctrl.Top + offsetTop
                    .Left = ctrl.Left
                End With

            End If
        End If
    Next ctrl

    btnAddClass.Top = btnAddClass.Top + offsetTop
    btnRemoveClass.Top = btnRemoveClass.Top + offsetTop
    Me.Height = Me.Height + offsetTop
End Sub

Private Sub btnRemoveClass_Click()
    Dim ctrl As Control, offsetTop As Integer

    offsetTop = 30

    For Each ctrl In Me.Controls

        If TypeName(ctrl) <> "CommandButton" Then
            If ctrl.Top = btnAddClass.Top - offsetTop Then
                Me.Controls.Remove (ctrl.Name)
            End If
        End If

    Next ctrl

    btnAddClass.Top = btnAddClass.Top - offsetTop
    btnRemoveClass.Top = btnRemoveClass.Top - offsetTop
End Sub
```

**Notes:**

To get this to work I need to explain the set-up:

1. Your initial row of controls have a `Top` property set to `12`
2. There are two buttons named `btnAddClass` and `btnRemoveClass` with `Top` set to `42`

The `offset` in height between the controls and the buttons is `30`.

To add new controls you simply loop over each control, create a new one, and set its `Top` to be the existing control `Top` value + the offset (i.e. 30). At the same time you shift the buttons down by 30 and increase the userform height by 30.

To remove controls you get the last row by checking the `Top` property relative to the `btnAddClass`. You then delete those controls and shift the buttons up by 30 and decrease the userform height by 30.

Comment: Thank You @alexp this works great. But, I do have a issue when I move the initial row from `Top` `12` to `42` and buttons at `78` the first textbox is out of place. Can you guide me with this? FYI, I have used `Me.ScroolHeight=Application.Height Me.ScroolWidth=Application.Width`. When I step into the code, I can see that both the textboxes are places correctly, but, the for loop continues to run.

Comment: Did you adjust the offset to 36 (i.e. 78 - 42)?

Comment: Yes, I did change the offset.

Comment: There was a bug in `Private Sub btnAddClass_Click`. I've updated it above. Does that solve the issue?

Comment: This is super perfect!! Thank you so much